# Unable to remove dynamically added row being added using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created below form to dynamically add rows. The + button is working perfectly fine, however while I try to remove the row from X button (added dynamically) it fails to remove the row and returns "Uncaught TypeError". This engages javascript and jquery.

While you run the snippet, please scroll down to see the results.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     var i=1;
     $('#add').click(function(){
          i++;
          $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Category" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions []" value="Yes &emsp;"> Yes &emsp; <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="No"> No</label></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
     });
     $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
          var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
          $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
     });
     $('#submit').click(function(){
          $.ajax({//here you can send date to DB
               url:"name.php",
               method:"POST",
               data:$('#add_name').serialize(),
               success:function(data)
               {
                    alert(data);
                    $('#add_name')[0].reset();
               }
          });
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-text"><div style="text-align: left">Deliverables</div></h5>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"><div style="text-align: left">Press + to add minors</div></h6>
        <button id="add" class="btn add-more"type="button">+</button>
        </div>
        
        
                <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <input type="hidden" name="count" value="1" />
        <div class="control-group" id="fields">
        <div class="controls" id="profs">
        <form id="main_delivery" class="input-append">
        <div id="field">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
                                    <tr>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Category" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                                         <td><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions []" value="Yes &emsp;"> Yes &emsp; <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="No"> No</label></td>
        </tr></table>
        </div>
        </form></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Attn: Press the + button multiple times to see the result in scroll bar.

Comment: Well there is not id on the row... and why are you using 1.4.1? That jQuery version is over 7.5 years old

Comment: The id on the row isn't necessarily needed either.  You could use `$(this).closest('tr').remove();` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         var i=1;
         $('#add').click(function(){
              i++;
              $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Category" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions []" value="Yes &emsp;"> Yes &emsp; <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="No"> No</label></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
         });
         $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
              var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
              $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
         });

         $('#submit').click(function(){
              $.ajax({//here you can send date to DB
                   url:"name.php",
                   method:"POST",
                   data:$('#add_name').serialize(),
                   success:function(data)
                   {
                        alert(data);
                        $('#add_name')[0].reset();
                   }
              });
         });
    });
```

Comment: I just added '<tr id="row'+i+'">' this part. You trying to remove row by ID but you didn't added yet by this line '$('#row'+button_id+'').remove();' Also update you jQuery version as well.

Answer (score 0):

[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) came to jQuery much later than v1.4.1.  Try updating to >= v1.7 or using [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).  Either way, you'll still need to bump up your version to at least v1.4.2 as that's the version where `.delegate()` was introduced.